# Flux architectures nested and non-singleton stores

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, flux

I get all my data on page load and the JSON looks as follows:

```
{
  users: [
    {
      userId: 1,
      messages: [
        {
          messageId: 1,
          lines: [/* array of lines */]
        },
        {
          messageId: 2,
          lines: [/* array of lines */]
        }          
      ],
    },
    {
      userId: 2,
      messages: [
        {
          messageId: 3,
          lines: [/* array of lines */]
        },
        {
          messageId: 4,
          lines: [/* array of lines */]
        }          
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

As an example of my problem, say I'm trying to implement a message selection feature. Each user can have one message `selected` at a time. When I call an action creator `selectMessage(messageId)` and that gets passed down to my `MessagesStore`, how do I know which user should have the message selected?

The only option I see is to pass the `userId` down the view hierarchy and then add that to the action creator - handling the action in the `UsersStore` rather than in the `MessagesStore`. Am I thinking about the architecture wrong?

Comment: Your making allot of assumptions in this question in regards to the business logic of the problem. what is an angle... what is a clip?? Make your question more generalised so its more usable by the community, not just your own problem domain.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan Sorry, can you be more clear as to what youre looking for? Maybe it should be phrased differently, but you can swap `angles` and `clips` for any other noun you'd like, its simply a question about nested data in stores and maintaining the singleton pattern. let me know how I can make that more clear.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan not sure if thats more clear. But I tried to make it less esoteric than `angles` and `clips` and rephrased the question. Let me know if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thank you, that is much clearer. I have approached this in the same manner simply passing down any arbitrary variables. Im sure there is a better way. I will look into this further and get back to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of which store to save it to depends on how you choose to relate stores to components. Some take the approach that each component should have its own store. (I don't). Others try to treat stores as resources (as in REST). It sounds like that's what you're learning to?

That can certainly work, too, but I have always found the fundamental idea of resources (as expressed in RESTful architectures) as somewhat artificial and limiting. I prefer to think of stores as collections of related data but without the strong structural cohesion of a resource.

That's rather a long-winded way of saying I think either approach you've outlined is fine. The question I try to ask myself is this: later, when my application becomes much larger, will it be obvious which store will hold a particular bit of data?